# Is the input to a pseudorandom process the random seed?

Tags: random-generation

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom#Almost_random)

> A pseudorandom variable is a variable which is created by a
> deterministic procedure (often a computer program or subroutine) which
> (generally) takes **random bits**  as input.  The pseudorandom string
> will typically be longer than **the original random string**, but less
> random (less entropic, in the information theory sense). This can be
> useful for randomized algorithms.

I was wondering if both "random bits" and "the original random string" mean the random seed which is also randomly chosen for the pseudorandom number generator?

Thanks!

Comment: they mean what you call the seed, yes. Note that there is no requirement that the "seed" is choosen randomly! Often it is specifically __not__ done that way, to make reproduction possible!

Comment: Thanks! But why it says the output pseudorandom numbers are "less random (less entropic, in the information theory sense)" than the seed, if the seed is not chosen randomly?

Comment: Where does it say so? Does not make any sense to me.  You should think more about the practical needs of your application of pseudo-random numers (¿Why do you use them?) and less about this "pseudo-philosphy".

Comment: In the quote. I dont have applications. Why did you type "¿" and how did you make it?

Comment: ¿Why ¿¿ ? How did I type it? I have a spanish (latin-american) keyboard, in spanish questions are started with ¿  and terminated with ?. I like to sprinkle it in english also!

Comment: @Tim also on US keyboards hold alt and type 168: ¿

Comment: @NickAlger:It doesn't work under Ubuntu and Firefox.